# videojs-youtube + videojs-playlist plugin

Tags: youtube, video.js

I have found various plugins of playlist for videojs. Some are need modification to run with latest version. I have also found plugin to run youtube video.

I need to know, is it possible to run both plugin at the same time. Like i want to run audio, video and youtube video through same player. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think [video.js](http://videojs.com) framework will help you

you can play youtube video on it, to do that you sholud write something like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <video
    id="vid1"
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls
    autoplay
    width="640" height="264"
    data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ"}] }'
  >
  </video>

  <script src="../node_modules/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../dist/Youtube.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the plugin itself [videojs youtube plugin](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube)

Comment: I already completed it. Solution is quite different then this.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Care to share your solution for the benefit of others?